# List of files from my google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I am writing PHP script which get files from my Google Drive folder and write list of them with download links on my website, but can not find solution which take files from my folder. Every solution I found need sign up from user, that is viewing page and get list of files from his google drive. Can anyone help me with solution?

Here is my code.

```
function printFilesInFolder($service, $folderId) {
  $pageToken = NULL;
  do {
    try {
      $parameters = array();
       $parameters = array(
        'q' => "'0B5NCdsbrL1VfQ00xY3pFS3BtOE0' in parents"
        );     
  $children = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
  var_dump($children);
  foreach ($children->getFiles() as $child) {
    print 'File Id: ' . $child->getId();
  }
  $pageToken = $children->getNextPageToken();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
  $pageToken = NULL;
}
  } while ($pageToken);
}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Web client 1");
$client->setClientId('CLIENTID');
$client->setClientSecret('SECRET');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));
$client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/googledrive/drive/drive.php');

if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) {
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$ret = printFilesInFolder($service,"FOLDERID");
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit();
}
```

But i still dont getting right data.

Second think is, that i want to remove need of authentication on every refresh of page, but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: Use the google offical docs to do this, https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list

Comment: I have edited my question. Cant use v2 API but v3 and there i cant use listChildren() like in v2 API and guess doing something wrong.

Comment: Try using the [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) to familiarized on what is the format of the response. Also in the [Notable changes : Migrating from Google Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration), "The fields query parameter should be specified for methods which return."